# has asciidoc preprocessor macros

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Hey exist in asciidoc a way to create preprocessor macros?

The macros in asciidoc allow me generate custom commands for the different output formats. My goal is the creation of valid asciidoc.

for example:

preprocessormacro: `#define pair() %1 and  %2`

use: `i think pair("a", "b") are the same`

result: `i think a and b are the same`

I hope you get the idea.
Attributes, specialwords and replacements don't fulfill this requirement. Or am i wrong?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: I see you posted the same question to the mailing list, that's probably the better place to seek answers as not many in the Asciidoctor community are watching SO for questions.

Comment: Yup thats me. For all others heres the link: http://discuss.asciidoctor.org/has-asciidoc-preprocessor-macros-td3282.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Jamal.

Jamal is a macro processor, which I created and it is also embedded as an asciidoc preprocessor.

I created Jamal for the very purpose you are looking for.

https://github.com/verhas/jamal